# How to exclude a module from webpack, and instead import it using es6

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, webpack-3

I am currently using webpack to bundle up a javascript file with react. This file also has another import statement to another module within my project

`import { MyModule} from './MyModuleFile.js'`

Is there a way to exclude MyModule.js from the webpack bundle, and instead keep the import as is?

Comment: Check out [Webpack docs about conditions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition): as @connexo suggests, you need to exclude the part you don't want Webpack to resolve in the Webpack configuration file.

Answer (score 10):

What you're after might be the [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) option in your `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
     './MyModuleFile': 'MyModule',
  }
};
```

This assumes you will include the script in your HTML manually which will expose the `MyModule` global

If you'd instead really like to use ES6 import, you could use the same technique because everything you put in there will just be exported as is

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
     './MyModuleFile': 'import("MyModuleUrl")',
  }
};
```

But make sure you use the async version of import

```js
import('./MyModuleFile').then(({default: MyModule}) => doSomethingWith(MyModule));
```

Or alternatively use the `webpackIgnore` comment to keep the import as is without changing the config

```js
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */'MyModuleUrl').then(({default: MyModule}) => doSomethingWith(MyModule));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  The webpack step works, but I get a "Error: Cannot find module" from webpackMissingModule, so its obviously still tying to use webpack, not the ES6 module loading from the browser directly. Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: What's your externals config and how do you import your file?

Comment: You can see all the details in this separate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050294/how-do-you-get-webpack-to-actually-ignore-an-external-and-rely-on-the-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: But I setup like this:

  externals: {
    '/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-webm.js': 'ffmpeg',
  },

Comment: And import like this :

  import ffmpeg from '/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-webm.js';

Comment: I've verified '/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-webm.js' is a valid address

Comment: You forgot to include the script in your html, adding it to externals does not include it for you. Eg: add `<script src="/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-webm.js"></script>` in the head of your app

Answer (score -4):

Just add it to the `exclude` option in your loader configuration of your `webpack.config.js`:

```
rules: [
  // rules for modules (configure loaders, parser options, etc.)
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: [
      /node_modules/,
      /MyModuleFile/
    ],
    ...
  }
]
```

> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-exclude

Comment: I thought that exclude will only exclude those files from being transformed, but they are still bundled.
I tried it out, and I see that my file is still included into the bundle, which is what I am trying to avoid.